# Strange behavior of Python's deepcopy with update

Tags: python, dictionary, deep-copy

So I try to make a deepcopy of dict and update it with some additional data (I don't want to change my original dict):

```
>>> a = {1:1}
>>> print(a)
{1: 1}
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(a).update({2:2})
>>> print(b)
None
```

But when I do it in another way, it works:

```
>>> a = {1:1}
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> b.update({2:2})
>>> print(b)
{1: 1, 2: 2}
```

Why Python sets `b` variable to `None` when I update on same line?

I've also try to make deepcopy of original dict:

```
>>> a = {1:1}
>>> a = copy.deepcopy(a).update({2:2})
>>> print(a)
None
```

But:

```
>>> a = {1:1}
>>> a = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> a
{1: 1}
```

So this is `dict.update` issue? Or maybe it's CPython related behavior?

Comment: This is literally in the **first line** of [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update): *"Return `None`."* I've no idea why you ever thought this was strange.

Comment: It seems that I've just overdone this. I was so confused and look for reason on deepcopy side

Comment: Your two versions weren't equivalent -`b = copy.deepcopy(a).update({2:2})` becomes `b = copy.deepcopy(a);` **`b =`** `b.update({2:2})`. This was never related to `deepcopy`.

Comment: Well, I understand. It's because I didn't know earlier about `mutators return None`. So I thought that `update` behave like `pop`. Now I know though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict.update` updates your dictionary in place, it does not return it so `b` is not what you think it is.